# Flutter/Dart- How to create a custom- shaped button such as this?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a three buttons such as showed in the image, but I am unsure how to do so. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating your own custom painter implementation.

Triangle Painter

```
class TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  final double strokeWidth;

  TrianglePainter({this.strokeColor = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 3, this.paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = paintingStyle;

    canvas.drawPath(getTrianglePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path getTrianglePath(double x, double y) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, y)
      ..lineTo(x / 2, 0)
      ..lineTo(x, y)
      ..lineTo(0, y);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TrianglePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.strokeColor != strokeColor ||
        oldDelegate.paintingStyle != paintingStyle ||
        oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth;
  }
}
```

USAGE

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: TrianglePainter(
              strokeColor: Colors.blue,
              strokeWidth: 10,
              paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 180,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```